# boto3 filter_log_events doesn't return cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I use python 3.7, boto3 1.9.196

there's multiple log streams in a single log group (more then 800)

group name : my-board

stream names : my-board-20191223-00, my-board-20191223-01 ... my-board-20191223-23

each stream names set with current datetime (YYYYMMDD-HH)

```
self._client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName=log_group,
    startTime=start_timestamp,
    endTime=end_timestamp,
    filterPattern=filterPattern,
    limit=limit,
)
```

eg) startTime : 2019-11-07 00:00:00, endTime : 2019-11-08 23:59:59

it returns multiple events

```
'events': [ blabla... ]
'searchedLogStreams':[
{
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191101-17',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, 
    blabla...
{
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191107-14',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191107-21',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191107-22',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191107-23',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191108-00',
    'searchedCompletely': False # FALSE
}]
```

eg2) startTime : 2019-12-23 00:00:00, endTime : 2019-12-24 23:59:59

but, it doesn't return any events!

```
'events': [], # EMPTY
'searchedLogStreams': [{
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191101-17',
    'searchedCompletely': True
},
    blabla...
{
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191102-17',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191105-16',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-13',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-14',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-19',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-20',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-21',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-22',
    'searchedCompletely': True
}, {
    'logStreamName': 'my-board-20191112-23',
    'searchedCompletely': True # TRUE
}]
```

I think it's because there's too many log streams

why it doesn't work? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you get a next token in the response, keep doing
There will be token that return nothing but there will be one with result you keep scrolling.

```
currentToken = response['nextToken']
response = client.filter_log_events(
        limit = 10000,
        filterPattern= filterPattern,
        startTime= start_timestamp,
        logGroupName= log_group,
        nextToken=currentToken)
print(response)
```

I was in same situation. My best guess is that the scrolling and the filtering are independent. If you remove the filter param (time, pattern in subsequence call you'll find it return events that does not match the initial call).

Comment: This worked for me as well. However, for short logs I get 2 valid/distinct `nextToken` (requiring 3 requests) before it keeps changing and I don't see any other indication to stop earlier

Comment: keep going until there's no more nextToken

Comment: Docs suggest stopping when the `nextForwardToken` is the same as provided. My point, however, is that you can still do 2 extraneous with no content which is a bit of a shame.

Comment: interesting that AWS API and SDK would behave like that.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused because the boto3 client returns a response before completely loading all the logs. Also, there is a limit(1 MB or 10000 events) on how many logs are returned in one response.
I faced the same situation and was able to use @HoaPhan's suggestion of using the nextToken. Here's how I set it up so that it would make as many requests as needed to get all the logs.

```
results = []

response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName = log_group,
    logStreamNamePrefix = prefix,
    filterPattern = pattern
)

results = results + response['events']

while 'nextToken' in response.keys():
     currentToken = response['nextToken']
      
     response = client.filter_log_events(
                logGroupName = log_group,
                logStreamNamePrefix = prefix,
                nextToken = currentToken,
                filterPattern = pattern
               )

     results = results + response['events']
```